# How to convert input text to image?

Tags: php, html, css, image, rating

I've created a rating star system that allows user to rate 1-5. 
How do I change the numbers 1-5 to stars?

These are the codes below that show the numbers for the user to rate.

```
 <?php foreach(range(1,5)as $rating):?>            
 <a href="rate.php?article= <?php echo $article->id; ?> &rating= <?php echo $rating ; ?> "> 
 <?php echo $rating; ?> </a>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Are there any ways I can convert them to an image or do I have to redo my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah for sure.

```
 <?php foreach(range(1,5)as $rating):?>            
 <a href="rate.php?article= <?php echo $article->id; ?> &rating= <?php echo $rating ; ?> "> 
 <?php echo '<img src="images/rating_'.$rating.'.png">'; ?> </a>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

Now simply create the folder images and insert rating_1.png, rating_2.png and so on.

BTW: Maybe it is easier and better for you when you use it in this way (only to show):

```
 <?php
      $bla = $article->id;    
 foreach(range(1,5)as $rating){        
 echo('
      <a href="rate.php?article='.$bla.'&rating='.$rating.'">
      <img src="images/rating_'.$rating.'.png">
      </a>
 ');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You have missing file extension `.png`, and `'` are wrongly placed

Comment: it's totally gone wrong now, you can't get values of `$article->id` / `$rating` inside single quotes, and quotes are still incorrectly placed!

Comment: "are there any ways i can convert them to image or do i have to redo my codes?" - you see, yes! & if there are some mistakes so edit it. This is only an example!

Comment: thanks for the help guys. it is sort of working but the image i've used doesnt load in the web though

Comment: it seems that ' '.$rating.' ' was breaking the image. I've removed them and it worked fine. Thank you all!!